# POI sax get Date from Cell

Tags: apache-poi, sax

I´m reading excel file with sax and everything is working expect dates. Dates are read like "41751" which is number of days from 1900. There should be some formatString, which I can use for formating, but it is null.

StartElement()

```
this.nextDataType = xssfDataType.NUMBER;
        this.formatIndex = -1;
        this.formatString = null;
        String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
        String cellStyleStr = attributes.getValue("s");
        if ("b".equals(cellType))
            nextDataType = xssfDataType.BOOL;
        else if ("e".equals(cellType))
            nextDataType = xssfDataType.ERROR;
        else if ("inlineStr".equals(cellType))
            nextDataType = xssfDataType.INLINESTR;
        else if ("s".equals(cellType))
            nextDataType = xssfDataType.SSTINDEX;
        else if ("str".equals(cellType))
            nextDataType = xssfDataType.FORMULA;
        else if (cellType == null) {
            maybeNull=true;
        } else if (cellStyleStr != null) {
            // It's a number, but almost certainly one
            //  with a special style or format
            int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(cellStyleStr);
            XSSFCellStyle style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
            this.formatIndex = style.getDataFormat();
            this.formatString = style.getDataFormatString();
            if (this.formatString == null)
                this.formatString = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(this.formatIndex);
        }
```

EndElement()

```
case NUMBER:
                    String n = value.toString();
                    if (this.formatString != null) {
                        thisStr = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double.parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex, this.formatString);
                        try {
                            int intV = Integer.valueOf(thisStr);
                            cv.set(CellTypes.INT, intV);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
                        if (cv.getType() == null) {
                            try {
                                Double doubleV = Double.valueOf(thisStr);
                                cv.set(CellTypes.DOUBLE, doubleV);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                cv.set(CellTypes.STRING, thisStr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

How can I get that date or how can I find, that cell contains date and not some integer. Full handler code is here http://pastebin.com/GveeMf4n
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Apache POI Example for converting a .xlsx file to .csv with SAX event parsing](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java), you'll see what you need to do

Basically, when you read the cell, not only do you need to capture the type and contents, but you also need to capture the `s` style index attribute, then look that up from the StylesTable which you load in a DOM-like way (it's small), eg

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                             Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
   this.formatIndex = -1;
   this.formatString = null;
   String cellStyleStr = attributes.getValue("s");
   if (cellStyleStr != null) {
       // It's a number, but almost certainly one
       //  with a special style or format 
       XSSFCellStyle style = null;
       if (cellStyleStr != null) {
           int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(cellStyleStr);
           style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
       } else if (stylesTable.getNumCellStyles() > 0) {
           style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(0);
       }
       if (style != null) {
           this.formatIndex = style.getDataFormat();
           this.formatString = style.getDataFormatString();
           if (this.formatString == null)
               this.formatString = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(this.formatIndex);
       }
    }

    // Rest of start element logic here
```

Then, when you get to the end tag for the cell, you can use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to format your cell's numeric contents (be that a Date, a %, or similar) based on the style you found earlier, eg

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        String thisStr = null;

    // v => contents of a cell
    if ("v".equals(name)) {
        // Process the value contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        switch (nextDataType) {
                case NUMBER:
                    String n = value.toString();
                    if (this.formatString != null)
                        thisStr = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double.parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex, this.formatString);
                    else
                        thisStr = n;
                    break;
```

Basically though, tricks are to read the `StylesTable`, capture the format string when your read the cell start, then use that to format the numeric string with DataFormatter when you have the cell contents.

Take a look at the [source code to the XLSX2CSV example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) for a working implementation of that

Comment: I´m doing this. I don´t see diference from in your code. I used XLSX2CSV as base. 
But formatString is null, so i cant be formated.

Comment: Did you correctly load the styles table? XLSX2CSV works perfectly for me for my excel files with dates in... Also, for a problematic cell, what's the XML snippet for the cell?

Comment: Sorry. I messed that styles. Now I´m getting 08/01/14 which is better. Can I test, if that cell is date?
if (formatString.equals("mm/dd/yy;@")) is not good solution I think. Thanks

Comment: The only way to tell it's a date is to get the format string, and compare that against the list of possible date / time elements. [DateUtil.isADateFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isADateFormat%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) can give you that

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.